# Ruby on Rails, Deploy via Capistrano setup error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I am setting up Capistrano in a rails project for first time. When I run "cap production deploy:check" it goes OK. But when I run "cap prodution deploy" it gives back the following error...

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@mysite.com: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@mysite.com: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory
```

I am using rails 4.2.3. Ruby 2.2.2(with RVM). I have the following gems added for capistrano on Gemfile...

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'capistrano-rvm', '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.4'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'
gem 'capistrano3-unicorn', '~> 0.2.1'
```

Comment: if you are using rvm, you will have to set rvm string in capistrano file for ruby version you are using. something like `set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ree@rails3'`

Comment: How do you mean "set rvm string for ruby version"? Were do I do that?

Comment: in `config/deploy.rb` file you should add rvm string that is basically ruby version and gemset you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `bundler` gem installed on the server.  The lines that look like this indicate that:

```
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory
```

You need to install the `bundler` gem on the server in order for capistrano to do it's thing.

Comment: I have the same problem (though not using rvm): which bundle returns which bundle
/home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/bundle, path shows echo $PATH
/home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:etc I can cd into the app folder manually on the server & run bundle install and it runs ok, just not under Cap 3